# Doctrine foreign key and onetoone anotation

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have entity below:

```
class InvoicingSystemOrders extends BaseEntity
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=false)
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  protected $orderId;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer",nullable=false)
   */
  protected $userId;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Model\Entity\SystemUsers",fetch="EAGER")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="user_id")
   */
  protected $user;
}
```

**userId** is foreign key from table with users and problem is, that if I can try insert new row, doctrine try save userId as NULL. If I was removing property user with anotation @OneToOne, doctrine save the row correctly with userId.

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO invoicing_system_orders (user_id) VALUES (?)' with params [null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Can you somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: If you have relationship defined, why do you want to have `user_id` defined explicitly? Remove `$userId` field and Doctrine handles relation itself.

Comment: Can you explain in some example, how to insert new row?